# How to deserialize and serialize a json string into array list of bean objects?

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, liferay-7

I have bean object say Documents having properties. And I have an `arraylist` as `List<Documents>`. I have a json string as follows:

```
[{"language"="English","Type"="fiction"},{}]
```

Language and type are properties of Documents class. I want to deserialize it into a `List<Documents>` using `JSONDeserializer` in `Liferay`.

Used Serialization implements and @JSON annotation on getters of documents class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: How can  a JavaScript answer be a answer to a question in Java